# Error:(8, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library

Tags: android

hi am trying to follow this tutorial

[Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

after i done everything am getting error in the manifest

```
Error:(8, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9                declared in library     C:\Users\Zezo2\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM1\app\build    \intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-    services\6.5.87\AndroidManifest.xml


Error:(8, 5) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than      version 9 declared in library C:\Users\Zezo2\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\6.5.87\AndroidManifest.xml
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms" to force usage
```

this is my build.geadle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:8'
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.androidhive.pushnotifications"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 16
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the library you are using has a minimum SDK version you need to adher too..

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9
```

you need to edit your Android project to update your minSdkVersion

- Update src/build.gradle - Make sure is the one under src folder
- Sync gradle button
- Rebuild project
- After updating the build.gradle minSdkVersion, you have to click on
  the button to sync gradle file ("Sync Project with Gradle files").

Comment: ok thank you so much , i change the minimum to 9 that work and the error go , but i got new error in the GCMIntentService.java . error is 
Error:(12, 30) error: package com.google.android.gcm does not exist

Comment: that is to do with the library I am guessing. You can try to ask a new question on here? As I have no idea about that.